# Convert a list of bools into an _int64

Tags: c++, list, boolean

I have a list of bools, and I am trying to convert it into one _int64.  The list of bools is being created by a string of 8 characters, so it will never go over a length of 64.

I tried doing this:

I pass a const std::list< bool >& binList into the function.

```
_int64 x = 0;
for(auto citer = binList.begin();citer!=binList.end();citer++{
    x*=10;
    if(*citer) x++;
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because if there is a list of 0's the int will never get larger, but the output I get doesn't even contain only 1's and 0's. It contains random numbers.  Not quite sure the best way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Asked for an example, so here is one:
binList contains:

{0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1}

When I run it through that loop, x = -3830736327776896713.

If it is not clear, I would LIKE x to contain 01101000011001011000110110001101111.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough _relevant_ code to determine what the problem is. Please put forth the effort to reduce your problem code to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include that in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shift left
2. Switch the last bit accordingly.

E.g.:

```
for(auto citer = binList.begin();citer!=binList.end();citer++){
    x <<= 1;
    if (*citer) x |= 1;
}
```

And perhaps better to have the int unsigned.

Comment: Or the second line can simply be `x += *citer;`.

Answer (score 1):

You're shifting to the next *base-10 digit* in your loop by multiplying by 10, you should be shifting to the next *bit* by multiplying by 2 instead.

Your odd results are probably caused by overflow, plus the fact that you're displaying it as a base-10 number instead of binary.

If your intent was really to use each base-10 digit as 0 or 1, you will only be able to hold 19 bits that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the boolean array and turn on `i'th` bit you find `1` in boolean array.

Following program turns the boolean array into a single 64 bit integer.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int turnOnBit(int N,int pos)
{
    return N=N | (1<<pos);
}

int main()
{
    bool ar[] = {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1};
    __int64 x;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(ar); i++)
    {
        if(ar[i])
            turnOnBit(x,i);
    }
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```